# Printing garbage at the end of a string

Tags: c, c-strings

Hi there i'm trying to print a new string dynamically allocated but it keep printing garbage at the end of the string.
The function need to delete any spaces & numbers from the given string.

```c
void main()
{
    char String[] = "123 Students & 5 Lectures";
    char* newString=clearDigitsAndSpaces(String);
    printf("New string is : %s ",newString);
    free(newString);
}

Appreciate any help possible. 

char* clearDigitsAndSpaces(char* String)
{
    int n = strlen(String);
    int i, count = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((String[i] >= 33 && String[i] <= 47) || (String[i] >= 58 && String[i] <= 128))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    char* newString = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((String[i] >= 33 && String[i] <= 47) || (String[i] >= 58 && String[i] <= 128))
        {
            newString[k] = String[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

The result i get is : "New string is : Students&Lectures²²²²" instead of "Students&Lectures"
Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Looks like `clearDigitsAndSpaces` doesn't keep the NULL terminator.

Comment: `void main()` is non-standard, please use `int main()`.

Comment: if you allocate with `calloc` instead of `malloc` it will initialize your buffer to all nulls.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons To avoid confusions with pointers and chars I prefer to call the last byte of a string the "zero terminator" or `'\0'` (or maybe `NUL` in special occasions) and keep `NULL` strictly for pointer contexts.

Comment: `malloc(count + 1)` (or `malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char))` if you insist), and set `newString[k] = '\0';` after the loop.

Comment: @Bathsheba ITYM `calloc(1 + count, sizeof(char))` (or `calloc(1 + count, 1)`).

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually I'd prefer `calloc(1 + count, sizeof(*newString))`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Ooh that's posh.

Comment: never cast a `malloc`! It returns a `void*` which is compatible with any pointer. Casting may hide a important error: forget to include `stdlib.h` (`malloc` would be supposed to return an int32 in place of a 64 bits pointer...)

Answer (score 2):

do a

```c
newString[k] = '\0';
```

at the end and allocate one more character.

And use correct datatypes (`strlen()` returns `size_t`, not `int`)

Comment: That will be UB as there isn't room for `NUL`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why?  There is needed exactly room for `count + 1`.

Comment: Oops, didn't read "and allocate one more character". Have an upvote for trolling your answer.