# function wmemcpy fills with garbage

Tags: c

i have concat function (it is necessary to write it yourself)

```
void *ConcatFirst(void *OldString) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wprintf(L"Input please\n");
    wchar_t *NewString;
    NewString = (wchar_t *) malloc(1000 * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wscanf(L"%ls", NewString);
    wchar_t *ConcatString;
    wprintf(L"%d\n", wcslen((wchar_t *) OldString));
    wprintf(L"%d\n", wcslen(NewString));
    ConcatString = (wchar_t *) malloc((wcslen(NewString) + wcslen((wchar_t *) OldString) ) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wmemcpy(ConcatString, OldString, wcslen((wchar_t *) OldString));
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", ConcatString);
    wmemcpy(ConcatString + sizeof(wchar_t) * wcslen((wchar_t *) OldString), NewString, wcslen(NewString));
    //*(wchar_t *)(ConcatString + wcslen(ConcatString)*sizeof(wchar_t)) = '\0';
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", ConcatString);
    free(OldString);
    free(NewString);
    OldString = (wchar_t *) malloc(wcslen(ConcatString) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wmemcpy(OldString, ConcatString, wcslen(ConcatString));
    free(ConcatString);
    return (void *) OldString;
}
```

I will give her an old string represented by `void*` as an input (this is how it should be). I read a new string in it and want to combine them. but after creating a new string and using `wmemcpy`, garbage is written to the end of the `ConcatString`, what should I do? input:
old string : "gfrds"
new string : "re"
after first wmemcpy : "gfrdsྱ"
after second : "gfrdsྱ"

Comment: please supply a small working program that shows the problem. We dont know how you are calling this function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing garbage at the end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798202/printing-garbage-at-the-end-of-a-string)

Comment: you need to 0 terminate your strings

Comment: @pm100 0 terminate after every wmemcpy?

Comment: You have commented out adding a nul-terminator to the string, and you haven't allocated space for said terminator. Also, don't take the length of an uninitialised string, as that is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: why are you using wmemcpy anyway, you should be using wcsncpy, and probably wcscat

Comment: @KenY-N i did what you said, and it didn't help. and new string dont add to old

Comment: @pm100 now it isnt garbage in the end. but now string dont concat (i used wscncpy, wcscat i cant use). input old string : "gfrds" new string : "re", output after first wcsncpy : "gfrds" after second: "re"

Comment: Also, `ConcatString + sizeof(wchar_t) * wcslen((wchar_t *) OldString)` is incorrect as `ConcatString` is of type `wchar_t *`, so use `ConcatString + wcslen((wchar_t *) OldString)` instead.